# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'should')'

Tags: javascript, mysql, chai

I'm getting  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'should')' when running the following. Why is that?

```
const {
  expect
} = require('chai');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHTTP = require('chai-http');
const should = chai.should()

chai.use(chaiHTTP);
//tester om man kan oprette annonce med rigtigt UserId
const endPoint = 'http://localhost:1000/lavAnnonce'

describe(`POST new user ${endPoint}`, () => {
  it(`should post a new Annonce`, (done) => {
    const payload = {
      title: 'DALDSADW',
      price: 50,
      location: 'hovedstaden',
      category: 'sko',
      colour: 'sort',
      billede: 'findes ikke',
      user_id: '180'
    };
    chai
      .request(endPoint)
      .post("")
      .set("content-type", "application/json")
      .send(payload)
      .end((err, response) => {
        response.should.have.status(200)
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is this happening on the line `chai.chould()` or `response.should.have.status(200)`?

Comment: If the latter, it's because `response` is undefined when there's an error. You need to check `err` first.